# 2 интернет соединения, как сделать стабильное подключение

Tags: сеть, сервер, linux

Есть два интернет подключения,

- А: статический выделенный айпи,   идет на прямую
- Б: статический выделенный айпи, идет через PPPoE, хочу использовать как запасное подключение.

Есть роутер dlink dir 615 с dd-wrt, linux машина с двумя сетевухами, и куча машин которые получают интернет через wifi.

Как программно или аппаратно сделать систему что бы при выключении одного интернета у всех пользователей включался другой? Возможно можно купить какую либо железку которая это умеет.

Answer (score 1):

bonding или скрипт, который, например, будет пинговать шлюз основного канала, в случае чего переключать канал.

Comment: то есть нужно 3 сетевухи на машину с линуксом и на нем все делать?

Comment: 2 или более с linux, на win боюсь так не получится.Вообще под bonding 615 с openwrt подойдет если на флешке есть место и каналы не слишком "широкие".

Comment: 30 мбит канал на одном и 2 мбит на другом, спасибо сейчас посмотрю про бондинг на роутере

Answer (score 0):

интересная тема, тоесть как я понял, только с linux'ом можно настроить две сетевухи в один bonding, в одну сетевуху будет подходить к примеру роутер, а во вторую подключение напрямую. И в случае дропов пакетов через роутер(один провайдер), соединение будет поддерживаться второй сетевухой(другой провайдер)?если что-то не так поправте пожалуйста.